# Scene7 URL parameters

Tags: adobe, scene7

Our business uses Adobe Scene7. One of the things we need to be able to do is share the URL of an image, to a vendor for all of the products with an image.

We have identified the construct of the URL to predict the link, and then we ping the image URL to ensure it is valid and available for viewing.

As of late, we've come into a problem where many of the images are not rendering...

Most images:

http://s7d5.scene7.com/is/image/LuckyBrandJeans/7W64372_960_1

Some images:

https://s7d9.scene7.com/is/image/LuckyBrandJeans/7Q64372_960_1

The only difference appears to be the s7d5 becomes s7d9 on some images. What drives that?

How do we get a list of all of those URL's if we can't predict the d9 vs d5?

Comment: This is from the Scene7 having many servers that drive the content. We can utilize any of the servers names and it will return the content. We used to use these back in the day when we http version 1 used to throttle too many references. I know this is an old thread but wanted to share my take on this one.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it matters. I think all you need is the filename. It looks like if you take the filename "7W64372_960_1" it works on both s7d5 and s7d3:

http://s7d5.scene7.com/is/image/LuckyBrandJeans/7W64372_960_1
http://s7d9.scene7.com/is/image/LuckyBrandJeans/7W64372_960_1

In fact, you can change it to s7d1, s7d2, s7d3, etc. and it still works.

So, I think if you were to build some sort of template you could just pick whatever URL you wanted and just append the filename on the end like:

http://s7d5.scene7.com/is/image/LuckyBrandJeans/{{imageFileName}}

Answer (score 0):

We have the same thing with our company.
One domain serves the images for the lower "sandbox" environment (d5) and the other serves the images to your live environment (d9).